# Hebrew words are not working in url in ie8 and ie9

Tags: php, character-encoding

i have url like :

```
http://www.example.com/search_page/?From=ISL&alphabet=א
```

And this url are working proper in safari,mozila but the in ie8 and ie9 is displaying in url  like

```
http://www.example.com/search_page/?From=ISL&alphabet=
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: If this happens when you go to `http://stackoverflow.com/?t=א` as well and the behavior is same, then it's not a #wordpress issue.

Answer (score 1):

Where does the url come from?

My guess is that the original link is not URL encoded.

Try accessing this link from your IE

```
http://www.example.com/search_page/?From=ISL&alphabet=%D7%90
```